# Which university is offering video courses in programming languages?

Tags: python

Frankly speaking. I'm looking for a specific video course webpage which I visited few months ago. It was posted as an answer to some question. I know this kind of questions are frowned upon and closed. But I'm helpless. I've been searching for it for more than a month and this is my last approach.

I'm writing a report on education methodologies. Professor taking that course was trying a new approach. I *need* to go through it once again to include that in my report. I'm really hoping that some one would give me link to that page. Here is the description of that course & webpage.

**Description of course & webpage:**

1. They were offering video courses in more than one language. AFAIR, languages were Python, Java, (Haskell).
2. First lecture of course is about his new approach of teaching. Prof mentions something like "unlike a traditional university course, this course doesn't have two or three big  exams or it  doesn't have cutoff marks and hence no pass or fail.  After each topic is taught they'll need to give a quiz. If they don't get around 70% then they'll have to keep on giving the test until he scores it.". He goes on to show some performance statistcs (he uses slides for this) of his previous students in previous programming courses and why he took this new approach. etc..etc.. I don't exactly remember it. But I was very much impressed with the concept. Now this is exactly what I'm after.
3. Also that prof's webpage has a time lapse of some building construction out side his room's window.

I wish I could start bounty now itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the wibsite, http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~selfpace/
you can see the video in the bottom of that page ,then you can redirect to the Youtube site
then download all the six video lectures.

Those are UCBerkerley CS courses .What you want is in the videos.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At last found it. :)

Answer (score 3):

This may not be it, but I would definitely recommend MIT Scheme courses:

http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=5546836985338782440#

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/

Comment: +1 This is not exactly what I'm looking for but teaching is really good.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about various video lectures on web?

- Programming methodology : http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=824a47e1-135f-4508-a5aa-866adcae1111
- Programming paradigm : http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=2d712634-2bf1-4b55-9a3a-ca9d470755ee
- http://dada.cs.washington.edu/dl/course_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good post by [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5615716/) with some of the relevant sites for learning for free online. One that is not listed in that post is http://webcast.berkeley.edu/ which I have found very beneficial.

Also check [here](http://www.thatchspace.com/2006/03/19/berkeley-mit-webcasts/)...long list of other places to grab what you may be looking for...perhaps it was not a university's direct offering...

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking through [Academic Earth's CS archive](http://academicearth.org/subjects/computer-science).